# Block insertion point does not match width and height of an image

Tags: autocad, cad, dxf

(all of the numbers are not real sizes)

I have an image in autocad which width: 8000mm and height:8000mm when I insert a block in the middle of the image instead the X and Y of the block to be (4000,4000) they are something like (560,560). Even when I move the block the X and Y are still the same. I have no idea why?!

I made some research and I saw that some of the people there are saying that sometimes the blocks have different coordinate system than the picture itself.

Can you tell me how I can figure out this so I can get X and Y for the block to be (4000,4000)?

Best regards,
Dimitar Georgiev

Answer (score 3):

The X and Y coordinates (or the origin) of your `BLOCK` entity don't have anything to do with where the `BLOCK` is placed in your drawing.

When you insert a `BLOCK` into a drawing, you are actually doing a couple of things.

First, AutoCAD creates an entry in the `TABLE` that is used to hold `BLOCK_RECORD` objects.  The `BLOCK_RECORD` that is created will have a handle that references the geometry of the `BLOCK` that has just been inserted.

This handle is then used in the `BLOCKS` section.  This section contains the `BLOCK` entities that define the geometry contained in the `BLOCK` itself.  One of the first entries in the `BLOCK` entity is a set of X and Y coordinates that represent the base point of the `BLOCK`.

These **are not** the same as the coordinates for where the `BLOCK` is actually inserted in the drawing.  These coordinates act as a reference point for all the geometry contained in the `BLOCK` object.  Every coordinate, for every piece of geometry in the `BLOCK` is referenced from the `BLOCK` base point.  You can think of all the coordinates for the geometry in the `BLOCK` object as delta coordinates, because they measure distance from the base point of the `BLOCK`, not from the origin of the drawing.

The last thing that AutoCAD does when you insert a `BLOCK`, is to create an `INSERT` object in the `ENTITIES` section.  This is a short entity that contains the name of the `BLOCK` being inserted as well as the coordinates where the `BLOCK` will be located in the drawing.  These coordinates are the ones that control the location of the `BLOCK` within the drawing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using `Kabeja Library` to read the `BLOCK` objects in `Java`. I am reading exactly the `ENTITIES` from type `INSERT` and the coordinates are still the same. I will debug the code again but I am 100% sure that I am reading them like that. Probably the problem is with the `Kabeja Library`. Is there any other free `DXF Libraries` out there which are better than `Kabeja` or at least with some more documentation. Because for the `Kabeja` library there isn't any?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Kabeja.  We roll our own dxf reader in-house, but it's in .NET.  I believe that there is a good C++ library called dxflib.